# UISplitViewController Barstyle changes when orientation changes

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

In my iPad app, I have the barStyle property set to UIBarStyleBlack by this code:

```
// in viewDidLoad
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Strangely, when I rotate my iPad, the barStyle will ***sometimes*** reset to the gray / grey color.  Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
}
```

will fix it.

Comment: I want to mark this as correct, but since this is a random bug, I will wait a bit longer.  However, I tried your suggestion and so far the barStyle hasn't changed on me.

Comment: This exact thing happened to me and had to move the code to viewWillAppear as you suggested. Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641845/ipad-splitview-changes-main-navigation-bar-color), which has an accepted answer that seems to me like it would work.

The information provided in that question help me understand the problem.  On rotation, different view controllers are being hidden and shown, and potentially, their properties deallocated.  The answer's author suggests using the delegate callbacks from `UISplitViewController` to find out when to re-set your bar style, not the standard UIView callbacks:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009454

Comment: No, this was happening before that release came out.